# How to identify selector id when initialize multiple Fullcalendar at one time?

Tags: fullcalendar

I initialize two calendars on same page as below:

**html**

```
<div id="calendar1"></div>
<div id="calendar2"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#calendar1, #calendar2").fullCalendar({
 .....
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var evt1=[{title:'A',start:'2015-02-01'}];
            var evt2=[{title:'B',start:'2015-02-01'}];

            calendarid = $(this);  <== how to get the id?

            if (calendarid = 'calendar1') { callback(evt1); }
            if (calendarid = 'calendar2') { callback(evt2); }                       

  }, // end of events
 .....
}
```

Each calendar got its own set of events.  How can I know the selector id inside the events function? Does fullCalendar expose $(this) property to let programmer code on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do it this way:

Create an array with your selectors and set it as custom option to the calendar configuration:

```
var calendars = ['calendar1', 'calendar2'];
for (var i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
    fullCalConfig.id = calendars[i];
    console.log(fullCalConfig);
    $('#'+fullCalConfig.id).fullCalendar(fullCalConfig);
}
```

Now you can look up the selector from within the `events` function:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var evt1=[{title:'A',start:'2015-02-01'}];
        var evt2=[{title:'B',start:'2015-02-01'}];
        calendarid = this.options.id;
        if (calendarid == 'calendar1') { callback(evt1); }
        if (calendarid == 'calendar2') { callback(evt2); }                       
  },
```

I set up a jsFiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/kqdzz5wq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried getting `$(this).attr('id');`inside the fullCalendar function? That should work.

If youre having problems, try using

`$("#calendar1, #calendar2").each().fullCalendar({etc..`

to ensure every object is called seperatly and then `$(this).attr('id');`inside the fullCalendar function will work.

Comment: Tested without luck. console.log('The id is:'+$(this).attr('id') ); return The id is: undefined.